# No space left: inodes

Tags: freebsd

when I do df

```
/dev/ada0p2  33927814 17086300 14127290    55%    /
devfs               1        1        0   100%    /dev
devfs               1        1        0   100%    /var/named/dev
```

It seems my system is using the devfs.... how can i direct my system to use the free space in dev/ada0p2?

Comment: Use the free space for what exactly?

Comment: devfs... it is quite a dew years since I last saw a devfs. How old is your software? Shouldn't you upgrade it?

Comment: You've been misled by the incorrect [tag:linux] tag that the questioner placed on the question, MariusMatutiae.  This is not Linux, and preconceptions about Linux devfs do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Inodes, blocks and percentage used are values that are not applicable to a pseudofilesystem like devfs.

A pseudofilesystem is a collection of directories and nodes that behaves like a filesystem in terms of you being able to navigate it with commands like cd and ls, but which does not store actual files.

The 100% shown for /dev doesn't mean that anything is full.  It is just an arbitrary value.    You can simply ignore the values that df displays for those filesystems. On some systems, the df command does not even display pseudofilesystems.

The only entry that df provides useful information about in your listing is the one for /dev/ada0p2.